# Positioning virtual assets with ARKit and SCNKit

Tags: ios, xcode, augmented-reality, arkit, scnnode

I'm trying to understand SCNKit and ARKit a little better and have a barebones Xcode 9 Augmented Reality app deployed and working on my iPhone (which I'm using as a simple test device).

This app's source code is [here](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/SynthetikDemo).

Basically, the app starts, the camera is initialized, and it renders a 3D fighter jet inside the scene (world view) in a similar fashion to how Pokemon Go injects monsters into your camera viewport (wherever your pointing your camera at). Pretty cool!

This code was all auto-generated for me by Xcode. So I'm trying to understand where the logic lives that determines *where* to position/orient the fighter jet (the SCN file titled `art.scnassets/ship.scn`). From [here](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/SynthetikDemo/blob/master/SyntheticDemo/ViewController.swift#L29) we see the jet being loaded:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Set the view's delegate
    sceneView.delegate = self
    
    // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true
    
    // Create a new scene
    print("Hello there Mr. Zac")
    
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
    
    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene
}
```

But I don't understand how the app chooses *where* to place the jet/ship and to orient it in which direction. I ask because as a first step I'd like to try repositioning the jet and then also swapping it out for my own asset files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "logic" for that, such as there is any, lives in two places.

1. The `ship.scn` file defines not just a model, but the model's position in the scene. (That is, in a global "world" coordinate space.)

   In the `scn` file that ships in that Xcode project template, the model is positioned at something like `0, 0, -0.5`, so if a camera is placed at the origin of the coordinate system, the ship appears directly in front of the camera, half a meter away.
2. ARKit itself defines scene/world space relative to the initial real-world position/orientation of the device. [By default](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/2923550-worldalignment), that coordinate system's z-axis matches the initial orientation of the device, so anything placed "in front of" the coordinate origin will appear in front of the camera when you start the AR session.

Comment: Ah thanks @rickster (+1) , when the apps starts up, what determines where the origin of the coordinate system is? Furthermore, does the `.scn` file just define the default/initial position of the model in the scene? Is there any way to override this default/initial position, as well as to update it after its been loaded to the scene? Thanks again!